# Rails 5.2 Import XLSX with ActiveStorage and Creek

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, import, sidekiq, rails-activestorage

I have a model called `ImportTemp` which is used for store imported XLSX file to database. I'm using ActiveStorage for storing the files.

this is the model code:

```
class ImportTemp < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_one_attached :file
  has_one_attached :log_result
end
```

this is my import controller code:

```
def import
  # Check filetype
  case File.extname(params[:file].original_filename)
  when ".xlsx"
    # Add File to ImportFile model
    import = ImportTemp.new(import_type: 'UnitsUpload', user: current_user)
    import.file.attach(params[:file])
    import.save

    # Import unit via sidekiq with background jobs
    ImportUnitWorker.perform_async(import.id)

    # Notice
    flash.now[:notice] = "We are processing your xlsx, we will inform you after it's done via notifications."
    # Unit.import_file(xlsx)
  else flash.now[:error] = t('shared.info.unknown')+": #{params[:file].original_filename}"
  end
end
```

after upload the xlsx file, then the import will be processed in sidekiq. This is the worker code (still doesn't do the import actually) :

```rb
class ImportUnitWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options retry: false

def perform(file_id)
  import_unit = ImportTemp.find(file_id)

  # Open the uploaded xlsx to Creek
  creek = Creek::Book.new(Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_blob_path(import_unit.file, only_path: true))
  sheet = creek.sheets[0]

  puts "Opening Sheet #{sheet.name}"
  sheet.rows.each do |row|
    puts row
  end

  units = []

  # Unit.import(units)
end
```

but after i tried it, it gives me error:

```
Zip::Error (File /rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBCZz09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--3960b6ba5b55f7004e09967d16dfabe63f09f0a9/2018-08-10_10_39_audit_gt.xlsx not found)
```

but if i tried to open it with my browser, which is the link looks like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBCZz09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--3960b6ba5b55f7004e09967d16dfabe63f09f0a9/2018-08-10_10_39_audit_gt.xlsx
```

it's working and the xlsx is downloaded. My question is what's wrong with it? why the file is not found in the sidekiq?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using `Tempfile` as suggested by George Claghorn. I don't know if this is the best solution or best practices, but it works for me now. I'm going to use this solution while waiting Rails 6 stable to come out with `ActiveStorage::Blob#open` feature.

```rb
def perform(file_id)
  import    = ImportTemp.find(file_id)
  temp_unit = Tempfile.new([ 'unit_import_temp', '.xlsx' ], :encoding => 'ascii-8bit')
  units     = []

  begin
    # Write xlsx from ImportTemp to Tempfile
    temp_unit.write(import.file.download)

    # Open the temp xlsx to Creek
    book   = Creek::Book.new(temp_unit.path)
    sheet  = book.sheets[0]

    sheet.rows.each do |row|
      # Skip the header
      next if row.values[0] == 'Name' || row.values[1] == 'Abbreviation'
      cells = row.values

      # Add cells to new Unit
      unit = Unit.new(name: cells[0], abbrev: cells[1], desc: cells[2])
      units << unit
    end

    # Import the unit
    Unit.import(units)
  ensure
    temp_unit.close
    temp_unit.unlink   # deletes the temp file
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks man, ive been searching for this so long, Im using rails 5 too. So this bypass is very handy!

Comment: you're welcome, i'm glad it can helps someone/anybody

Answer (score 2):

`Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_blob_path` doesn’t return the path to the file on disk. Rather, it returns a path that can be combined with a hostname to produce an URL for downloading the file, for use in links.

You have two options:

- If you’d prefer to keep `ImportUnitWorker` indifferent to the storage service in use, “download” the file to a tempfile on disk. Switch to Rails master and use `ActiveStorage::Blob#open`:

  ```
  def perform(import_id)
    import = ImportTemp.find(import_id)
    units  = []

    import.file.open do |file|
      book  = Creek::Book.new(file.path)
      sheet = creek.sheets[0]

      # ...
    end

    Unit.import(units)
  end
  ```
- If you don’t mind `ImportWorker` knowing that you use the disk service, ask the service for the path to the file on disk. `ActiveStorage::Service::DiskService#path_for(key)` is private in Rails 5.2, so either forcibly call it with `send` or upgrade to Rails master, where it’s public:

  ```
  def perform(import_id)
    import = ImportTemp.find(import_id)
    units  = []

    path   = ActiveStorage::Blob.service.send(:path_for, import.file.key)
    book   = Creek::Book.new(path)
    sheet  = creek.sheets[0]

    # ...

    Unit.import(units)
  end
  ```

Answer (score 1):

The answer now seems to be (unless I am missing something):

```
Creek::Book.new file.service_url, check_file_extension: false, remote: true
```